# Why Isn't This Module Visible?

Tags: module, rust, visibility

I'm coding a hash in Rust for practice.  The code looks like this:

```
pub fn get_fnv1a32(to_hash:&str) -> u32{
   const OFFSET_BASIS:u32 = 2_166_136_261;
   const PRIME:u32 = 16_777_619;

   if !to_hash.is_empty(){
      let mut hash = OFFSET_BASIS;
      for b in to_hash.bytes(){
         hash = hash ^ (b as u32);
         hash = hash.wrapping_mul(PRIME);
      }
      hash
   }
   else
   {
      0
   }
}
```

And this is the code I'm trying to use to test this:

```
mod fnv;
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn get_correct_hash(){
        assert_eq!(0x7a78f512, fnv::get_fnv1a32("Hello world!"));
    } 

    #[test]
    fn hash_handles_empty_string_correctly(){
        assert_eq!(0, fnv::get_fnv1a32(""));
    }
 }
```

The test code is in lib.rs and the `get_fnv1a32` function is in fnv.rs.  They're both in the same directory. But when I try to run cargo test I keep getting these messages:

```
Compiling hashes v0.1.0 (U:\skunkworks\rust\hashes)
warning: function is never used: `get_fnv1a32`
 --> src\fnv.rs:1:8
  |
1 | pub fn get_fnv1a32(to_hash:&str) -> u32{
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `fnv`
 --> src\lib.rs:7:32
  |
7 |         assert_eq!(0x7a78f512, fnv::get_fnv1a32("Hello world!"));
  |                                ^^^ use of undeclared type or module `fnv`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `fnv`
  --> src\lib.rs:12:23
   |
12 |         assert_eq!(0, fnv::get_fnv1a32(""));
   |                       ^^^ use of undeclared type or module `fnv`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I tried changing the `mod fnv;` line at the top to `pub mod fnv;` and that gets rid of the dead code warning but it doesn't fix the two errors. What do I need to do to get the `get_fnv1a32` function to be visible in the lib.rs file?

Not that I would think it would matter but the version of rustc is *rustc 1.41.0 (5e1a79984 2020-01-27)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test module is separate from the outer module. Add

```
use super::*;
```

or an equivalent statement like `use crate::fnv` inside the `tests` module to make the `fnv` module visible.

Comment: That fixes it but could you clarify something for me.  What do you mean "separate from the outer module"?

Comment: By analogy with a filesystem, names like `fnv::get_fnv1a32` function like relative paths: If you are in the root module of your crate (lib.rs), which is like `/`, there is a submodule (like a subdirectory) `fnv` and a submodule `tests`. To refer to the function `fnv::get_fnv1a32` from within the test submodule, you basically have to use either `super`, which would be like saying `../fnv/get_fnv1a32`, or `crate`, which is like saying `/fnv/get_fnv1a32`. Does this help?